# Using scanf into global or local variables (on the stack), 32-bit calling convention

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, scanf, att

Given the following code :

```
    .section    .rodata
str:    .string "Hello World!\n"
input:  .long 2
    ########
    .text
.globl  main
    .type main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,   %ebp

    pushl   $str
    call    printf

    #return from printf:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    %ebp,%esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

The output would be "Hello World!".

---

**Now I try to get a number from the user** , and then print it out on the screen , but
it doesn't work (code compile,but I did something wrong) .
Where is my mistake ?

```
    .section    .rodata
input:  .long   2
    ########
    .text
.globl  main
    .type main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,   %ebp
    pushl   %ebx    

    call    scanf  # call scanf to get number from the user
    popl    input  # store the number entered by user in input (variable)
    pushl   input  # push it back into the stack
    call    printf # print input

    #return from printf:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    %ebp,%esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what sort of assembler you're using, however I could get your code to compile with gcc so I stuck with your formatting style (not talking about the AT&T syntax).

Anyway, you should check the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html) for `scanf` and realise that it takes a **format string** and **pointers** to locations in memory of where to store the values read in. It also **returns the number of successfully read items** and not what was read.

Now do the same and check the [documention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) for `printf`. You'll see that a format string is required to print your number in a readable form. A suitable format string is `"%d\n"` to print the number and a newline.

Your code could now look something like this (which compiles and works fine for me with gcc):

```
.section .rodata

input_format:  .string  "%d"
output_format: .string  "%d\n"

.section .bss
input:  .long  0          # reserve 4 bytes of space

.section .text
.globl  main
    .type main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,   %ebp

    pushl   $input    # push the ADDRESS of input to have the value stored in it
    pushl   $input_format   # give scanf the ADDRESS of the format string
    call    scanf    # call scanf to get number from the user
    addl    $8, %esp # clean up the stack
    
    # Note the return value of scanf is passed through eax (same for printf)
    
    pushl   input    # pass the number to printf BY VALUE
    pushl   $output_format  # pass the ADDRESSS of the output format string to printf
    call    printf   # print input

    #return 0 from main:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    %ebp,%esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Note that I would normally use `db/dw/dd` for allocating memory in the `.(ro)data` and `.bss` sections as opposed to `.string` and `.long`, so if that part's done slightly wrong you could just fix it up.

You could also use stack space for storing the number, however you already had `input` declared and I wanted to leave the code as similar to what you had as possible. Same goes for everything else before and after the `scanf` and `printf` stuff, I just left that as your code.

**EDIT:** Here's an example of using the stack to create a local variable, as opposed to having a variable declared in the `.bss` or `.data` segment:

```
.section .rodata

input_format:  .string  "%d"
output_format: .string  "%d\n"

.section .text
.globl  main
    .type main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,   %ebp

    subl    $4, %esp       # allocate 4 bytes on the stack for a local variable

    # The local variable will be at -4(%ebp)

    leal    -4(%ebp), %eax # get the ADDRESS of our local variable
    pushl    %eax          # push the ADDRESS of the variable on the stack
    pushl   $input_format  # give scanf the ADDRESS of the format string
    call    scanf          # call scanf to get number from the user
    addl    $8, %esp       # clean up the stack

    # Note the return value of scanf is passed through eax (same for printf)

    pushl   -4(%ebp)       # pass the number to printf BY VALUE
    pushl   $output_format # pass the ADDRESSS of the output format string to printf
    call    printf         # print the input

    #return from printf:
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    %ebp,%esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: First of all - thanks ! second , how can I do that without using globals (i.e. 'input' variable) and use the stack instead ? thanks a lot again !!

Comment: @ron: You can subtract the stack pointer by 4 to "allocate" a variable of size 4 bytes, and pass the address of that position on the stack to `scanf`. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: `input:  .long` reserves zero bytes of space.  You want `.long 0` in your version using globals (fixed it for you).

Comment: In your version using local variables (stack space), you can simply `push %esp` to push a pointer to the space you reserved.  But doing it with LEA relative to the frame pointer maybe shows the concept better, especially if you bother to set up EBP as a frame pointer at all.  (BTW, beware that modern versions of the i386 System V ABI on Linux require / guarantee maintaining 16-byte stack alignment, not just 4.  i.e. 3 x 4-byte pushes / adjustments to ESP after function entry, unlike what this is doing.  On GNU/Linux printf usually won't actually fault from this, though).

Answer (score 3):

Your arguments to [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) are incorrect, you need to push both a scan format and buffers to hold the types that you are looking for, then, if they aren't strings, you need to push a new formatting string to `printf`, in this case `"%d"`.

it would look a little like this (sorry its in Intel/MASM format):

```
SUB ESP,4 ;make stack space for an int
LEA EAX,[ESP]
PUSH EAX
PUSH offset NumberString ;"%d"
CALL scanf
PUSH [ESP+8] ;our scanned number
PUSH offset NumberString ;"%d"
CALL printf
ADD ESP,20 ;clean up for the cdecl funcs and the alloc'ed stack space
```

Comment: note that you could `push esp` (which is guaranteed to store the original value: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push), and that `lea eax, [esp]` is a silly inefficient alternative to `mov eax, esp`.